# How do you undo this command - sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local

Tags: terminal, sudo

I ran this command and I think it has screwed up my SASS:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

Any suggestions on how to undo this command on a MAC?

Comment: Restore from backups, or reinstall stuff. There is generally no audit trail kept that remembers the previous ownership of files. Depending on what all you have in `/usr/local`, you could possibly just do another `chown -R something` of various portions of it (probably the majority of each subdirectory was owned by specific users).